# Dplyr top_n returns multiple rows

Tags: r, dplyr

Dplyr provides a function top_n(), however in case of equal values it returns all rows (more than one). I would like to return exactly one row per group. See the example below.

```
df <- data.frame(id1=c(rep("A",3),rep("B",3),rep("C",3)),id2=c(8,8,4,7,7,4,5,5,5))
df %>% group_by(id1) %>% top_n(n=1)
```

Comment: `top_n` based on which column? `id1` or `id2`? FYI: `top_n` is superseded. You should use `slice_max` instead

Comment: or `slice_head` you just want the first row for each group

Comment: You can sort the values in each group and just the take the top n

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a combination of `arrange` and `slice`

```
df %>% 
  group_by(id1) %>% 
  arrange(desc(id2)) %>% 
  slice(1)
```

Use `desc` with in arrange if you want the larges element otherwise leave it out.

Apparently also `slice_head` is the new name of the function that you are looking for

```
df %>% 
  group_by(id1) %>% 
  arrange(desc(id2)) %>% 
  slice_head(id2, n=2)
```

Comment: I tried this and now realised that another package Iranges overrider the slice function. Thanks for your answer

Comment: `slice_head()` doesn't sort data. It just subsets the first n rows.

Answer (score 1):

Use `slice_max()` with the argument `with_ties = FALSE`:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(id1) %>%
  slice_max(id2, with_ties = FALSE)

# A tibble: 3 x 2
# Groups:   id1 [3]
  id1     id2
  <chr> <dbl>
1 A         8
2 B         7
3 C         5
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to remember so many `{dplyr}` function names that are prone to be changed anyway, I can recommend the `{data.table}` package for such tasks. Plus, it's faster.

```r
require(data.table)
df <- data.frame(id1=c(rep("A",3),rep("B",3),rep("C",3)),id2=c(8,8,4,7,7,4,5,5,5))
setDT(df)
df[ ,
    .(id2_head = head(id2, 1)),
    by = id1 ]
```