# Filter and select dataset in r

Tags: r

Using the mtcar dataset I want to find the top 2 cars with the highest mileage and after knowing that information I want to create a new data frame that has info of only those 2 cars with all the remaining info like horsepower, gear, cylinder, and so on. Please let me know how could I do that

```
cars<-mtcars %>% 
          group_by(mpg) %>% 
          count(mpg)
```

So with this, I get 32.9 and 32.4 as best mpg now how do I add all the other info in a new data frame that has info about these 2 cars. Please let me know. Thank you!

Comment: `dplyr::count` counts how many times a group occurs. It's not going to give you a maximum value

Comment: Also see https://stackoverflow.com/q/27766054/5325862, https://stackoverflow.com/q/63793757/5325862, and https://stackoverflow.com/q/53994497/5325862

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `top_n` from `dplyr`.

```
library(dplyr)

top2mpg <- mtcars %>% top_n(2, mpg)
```

|  | mpg | cyl | disp | hp | drat | wt | qsec | vs | am | gear | carb | FIELD13 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Fiat | 128 | 32.4 | 4 | 78.7 | 66 | 4.08 | 2.200 | 19.47 | 1 | 1 | 4 | 1 |
| Toyota | Corolla | 33.9 | 4 | 71.1 | 65 | 4.22 | 1.835 | 19.90 | 1 | 1 | 4 | 1 |

Answer (score 1):

We may use `slice_max`

```
library(dplyr)
mtcars %>% 
    slice_max(n = 2, order_by = "mpg")
```

---

Or use `arrange` and `slice`

```
mtcars %>% 
    arrange(desc(mpg)) %>%
    slice_head(n = 2)
```

-output

```
                 mpg cyl disp hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
Toyota Corolla 33.9   4 71.1 65 4.22 1.835 19.90  1  1    4    1
Fiat 128       32.4   4 78.7 66 4.08 2.200 19.47  1  1    4    1
```